# Do I need to book a round-trip ticket to Tbilisi, Georgia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, georgia-country, proof-of-onward-travel, tbilisi

I am Nigerian and have never been to Tbilisi, Georgia. I will be entering the country with a UK visa, so I booked a one-way ticket.

Do I have to book a round-trip ticket since I have not been there before?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ni&DE=ge&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Warning:
>   - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused
>     entry.

While I myself have only ever been asked for a return ticket once (which was not in Georgia), it is possible citizens of poorer countries will be subject to more scrutiny.

Thus, you should at least buy a refundable ticket, bring the confirmation to the border, and cancel it once in Georgia

Comment: If you're from a rich country you get 365 days on arrival. It might literally be impossible for you to buy an onwards ticket if you plan to stay for a full year.

Comment: @JonathanReez Even when entering the US and Japan (90 days), Montenegro (30 days) and Georgia back when we got 90 days, I've never ever been asked for a ticket. The only time ever was entering Moldova by train, when I said I wouldn't be exiting the way I came, but by air.

Comment: [sarcasm]Moldova is too rich to accept such Swiss strangers without return ticket [/sarcasm] :)

Comment: @Suncatcher Swedish* :)